# Untranslated strings page is empty

Tags: support, localization, russian-stackoverflow, international-sites, spanish-stackoverflow

[There was](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2718/176217) an [untranslated strings page](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/translation/missing) for ruSO at least. It's not working anymore, i.e. the page is exist, but there are no strings.

Is it a bug, or intentional behavior?

Comment: Same in other SOxx sites -> https://pt.stackoverflow.com/translation/missing, https://es.stackoverflow.com/translation/missing, https://ja.stackoverflow.com/translation/missing

Comment: possibly all strings already translated?

Comment: @Grundy no, Nicolas has asked devs about it, it's a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same question was presented in our community (SO.ja), and the staff received an answer with the [following comments](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3605/%e6%9c%aa%e7%bf%bb%e8%a8%b3%e3%81%ae%e3%83%95%e3%83%ac%e3%83%bc%e3%82%ba-%e3%83%9a%e3%83%bc%e3%82%b8%e3%81%af%e6%a9%9f%e8%83%bd%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%81%be%e3%81%99%e3%81%8b#comment3567_3607).

> we do not use /translations/missing anymore. Thank you! - [Nicolas Chabanovsky](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/274323/)

The corresponding page seems not to be currently used.